# secured connection between javascript client and python server

Tags: javascript, python, ssl, websocket, java-websocket

i have python server(with the help of asyncio and websockets module) and js client(with the help of websockets library) that are connected. The problem is that i need this connection to be secured (i'm working on passwords), but i had no success on establishing a connection with wss(web socket secure) - the code runs only with ws.
I even tried to establish my own encryption with RSA and AES but that also didn't work.
i'm really hopeles about it so if anyone ever did it or know a little about it, pls help me figure out what's wrong with it, or a direction to a rigth solution for secured connection that will work.

here's my server:

```
async def app(websocket, path):
while True :
    data = await websocket.recv()
    if (data== "close"):
        print("connection with client closed.")
        break
    data = data.encode()
    arr = data.split("~".encode())
    for i in range(0,4):
        arr[i]=arr[i].decode()
    resualt=algo(arr)
    await websocket.send(resualt)
```

start_server = websockets.serve(app, '0.0.0.0', 6169)

and my client:

```
 var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:6169/");
                    socket.onopen = function (evt) {
                        socket.send(st);
                    };
                    socket.onmessage = function (evt) {
                        alert("scrool extension page down to see the password");
                        $('#res').val(evt.data);
                        socket.send("close");
                    };
                    socket.onerror = function (evt) {
                        alert("the error is: "+evt.data);
                    };
```

in the python script we tried to use ssl:

```
c = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
```

c.load_default_certs(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)

start_server = websockets.serve(app, '0.0.0.0', 6169, ssl=c)

and in the js sciprt we wrote instead of the ws, wss:

```
"ws://127.0.0.1:6169/")
```

and the error we get:

```
 WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:6169/' failed: Error in connection
establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

Comment: Well WSS is the way to secure the data over the wire, you need to show how you tried to use it and the symptoms/errors relating to its failure.

Comment: first of all, i updated the question. And i know this is the way, i searched all over the web but i had no success on establishing it @AlexK.